# How to implement the following integral in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, discrete-mathematics

I am using Matlab to compute the following integral:

[image]

I want to know what is the best method to do this integral(trapez ...ect), and how to write it down.

this formula is called . ***The Integral of Time multiply Absolute Error (ITAE).***

where **epsilon** is the error vector, and **t** is a vector that has been generated as follow

```
t = 0 : 0.0001 : 10
```

here both **epsilon** and **t** have the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using [trapz](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html):

```
t = 0 : 0.0001 : 10;
epsilon = sin(t*3 - pi/6).*exp(-0.2*t); %Example for epsilon
ITAE = trapz(t, t.*abs(epsilon))
```

Result:

```
ITAE =

    9.4006
```

Comment: Hi Omar, can you please tell me if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **t*epsilon'**? Where the " **x'** " means transposition of **x**.
Then just try to add elements in matrix like **sum(resultMatrix)**.

Comment: you mean that I should write as follow:
`ITAE = sum(t*(abs(E))')`

Comment: Don't forget to multiply by dt.